# How can i link two tables and get the values in progress 4gl

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

i have two table employee and  order ,where as emp-id (field)is common in both the tables.i need to get emp-name and emp-ph form employee table, and order-num from order table.how to link these table and get the values

```
define variable c as integer.
define query q1 for customer,order SCROLLING.


INPUT FROM Value ( "C:\src\New folder\cnum.txt"). 


IMPORT c.


open query q1 for each employee where employee.emp-id=c ,
each  order where  (order.emp-id  = employee.emp-id ).
```

> it is throwing me error as conflict from query Browse use

Comment: You seem to use a third table "customer" in your code? How does it fit in?

Comment: Your question does not describe the answer that you accepted.  You should edit it to reflect what you really need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get the employee IDs from the text file, this should do it. It'll read the ID on each line of the file, find the employee record and display the order info.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE c AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

INPUT FROM VALUE("C:\src\New folder\cnum.txt"). 

REPEAT:
    IMPORT c.

    FIND FIRST Employee WHERE Employee.Emp-ID = c NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
    IF NOT AVAILABLE(Employee) THEN 
    DO:
        MESSAGE "Cannot find employee with ID " c VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR.
        NEXT.
    END.

    FOR EACH Order NO-LOCK WHERE Order.Emp-ID = Employee.Emp-ID:
        DISPLAY
            Employee.Emp-Name
            Employee.Emp-Ph
            Order.Order-Num.
    END.
END.

INPUT CLOSE.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the query for both tables:

```
DEFINE QUERY q1 FOR Customer, Order SCROLLING.
```

Comment: thank you, but still i am not able to get the values since order-num i have not used in  the query . could you please help in getting the order-num and i have re-written the code by replacing the customer table by employee table.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements do not mention a customer table nor do you require input from a file so I will focus on what you say that you need:

```
for each employee no-lock,
    each order no-lock where order.emp-id = employee.emp-id:

  display employee.name employee.emp-ph order.order-num.

end.
```